# Using powershell to Set-WebConfigurationProperty on a web application with a parent site

Tags: powershell, iis, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to modify [this Octopus Deploy step template](http://library.octopusdeploy.com/#!/step-template/actiontemplate-iis-application-create) to enable anonymousAuthentication on the newly created application

My application has a parent site, so it's going to be something like

`MyParentSite\MyChildSite`

Is it possible to target the parentSite \ name something like the below?

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty  
-filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication  
-name enabled  
-value true 
-location $parentSite\$name
```

Or am I using the wrong property?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're aware but you can set "Anonymous Authentication" using the default NuGet package deployment step. It's as simple as clicking a checkbox.

Within the built-in "Deploy a NuGet Package" step, click on "Configure features" towards the bottom of the step. Select "IIS website and application pool". From there, you should see these options:

[image]

You can definitely script out your solution if you so choose, but a lot of people don't realize this menu exists by default within Octopus because it's buried in the "Configure features" settings. I realize you're asking a PowerShell question and I'm responding with a non-PowerShell answer, but this may be the *simpler* path to getting what you want.

Comment: guess i should have clarified this in the question - the 'standard' nuget deployment step doesn't allow me to deploy to a virtual directory under a website, hence the need for the powershell step

Comment: Ah. Ok, thanks for clarifying. You did say child site and the step is for a parent IIS site. My bad. I'm not familiar with the Set-WebConfigurationProperty but your path appears to be correct. I think the location could be swapped out for: "-PSPath IIS:\"

Comment: it's not my preferred set up, but there's various annoying and immovable reasons I have to use virtual directories / parent sites etc...

Comment: Have you tried using the PowerShell WebAdministration module? This Set-WebConfigurationProperty looks ideal, but I'm wondering if another module is better.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a forward-slash instead of a backslash:

`Set-WebConfigurationProperty
-filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication
-name enabled
-value true
-location $parentSite/$name`